# Young Adult Sci-Fi book about Aliens Ruling Earth and a Human Resistance

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, young-adult

I am looking for a book about aliens ruling Earth and there is an underground rebellion. I read this over 20 years ago, so only certain parts stick in my mind.

I believe it took place on the west coast of North America, and the book may start in Northern California or even San Francisco.

The book starts with a raid against the human rebels. A boy escapes. This is the main character throughout the books. I believe there were other aliens as well that are described in the book and one of them is globes sitting on top of other globes.

I want to say the spaceships used by the aliens are triangular, but I could be wrong. I think the humans win, but can't be certain. I believe there is a part in the woods where they confront the aliens in a base or something similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been looking for this book too. I remember that there were two different species of aliens involved. The first species had given humanity technology while the second were invaders. A girl from the first alien race accompanied the human boy. I think she had purple skin and claws instead of feet. I'm pretty sure the boy was 15 years old.

*edit*
I think this is it! [*Under Alien Stars*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0689316216) by Pamela F. Service.

Comment: Thank you Naill C. !!!! That most certainly is the book. I have been looking for it for years. Now I will be ordering it from Amazon!!!

Answer (score 4):

The Tripods series, by John Christopher? The aliens sit in walking tripods. They enslave humans with thought-controlling caps. Children can't be fitted with caps (their skulls are still growing), so they can resist.

- *The White Mountains*
- *The City of Gold and Lead*
- *The Pool of Fire*
- *When the Tripods Came* (prequel)

Comment: By John Christopher, I think you mean. And don't his stories take place in the UK?

Comment: Yea, this could be one of many different YA sci-fi series. But John Christopher/Samuel Youd's _Tripod_ trilogy is my personal favorite and what my mind went to first when I read the title. But I believe James is right; they crossed the sea from England to mainland Europe, I think. Also, the prime trilogy consists of: _The White Mountains_, _The City of Gold and Lead_, _The Pool of Fire_. And then of course there's the prequel (_When the Tripods Came_).

Comment: No, it wasn't the Tripods series. I looked into that when I get google responses.

Answer (score 2):

Are the resistance all children? Do they have the power to turn into animals? Does being able to turn into animals prove surprisingly useful to their effort? Could be *Animorphs* by K. A. Applegate. There are tens of books in the series. The aliens are called Yerks, I can't remember much more.

Comment: No, the resistance weren't all children, just happens to follow one kid whose parents were involved in it, but he didn't realize it until they are raided. No turning into animals or anything like that.